# How to ensure that in flask WTForms, a form field is only tested for validity after it has been filled in?

Tags: python-3.x, flask-wtforms

I am trying to create a search form for a website where you can find movie reviews. As such, the user should be able to search for their movie by entering either the movie title or the imdb id or the year of release. However, the user should also not be allowed to search with a blank form.

```
class SearchForm(FlaskForm):
movie_title = StringField('Movie Title', validators=None)
imdb_id = StringField('IMDB_ID', validators=[Length(min=9,max=9)])
year = IntegerField('Year of Release', validators=[Length(min=4,max=4)])
submit = SubmitField('Search')
```

This is my current form.
However, due the length validtors in place for imdb_id and year, the user is unable to submit the form if they leave the beforementioned two fields empty as an empty field does not meet the minimum length of 9 and 4 respectively. Is there anyway to work around this such that a form is only validated if it is filled in?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a method which checks all the appropriate fields and ensures that at least one has content. Then you can check the prerequisite in the form validation method.

```
class SearchForm(FlaskForm):
    # ....

    def any_fields_filled(self):
        return any(self.movie_title.data, self.imdb_id.data, self.year.data)

    def validate(self):
        return self.any_fields_filled()
```

Then you need to mark the fields as Optional, e.g.:

```
imdb_id = StringField('IMDB_ID', validators=[Optional(), Length(min=9,max=9)])
```

If you find yourself needing to consult `any_fields_filled()` as part of one of the `validators` you declare on an individual field, you can either use a method instead (`validate_field_name()`) or you can use the [If() validator](https://wtforms-components.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#if-validator) in the WTForms-Components library.